KServe cert-manager HTTP-01 Challenge Fails With ‘Connection Reset by Peer’ for One InferenceService—but Not Others
Context
I’m running Knative and KServe in a Kubernetes cluster to serve ML inference workloads. I’m using cert-manager with an ACME ClusterIssuer (pointing to Let’s Encrypt) to issue TLS certificates.
Most of my Inference Services successfully get a certificate and become Ready. However, there’s one particular Inference Service (let's assume “Service A”) that fails to get a certificate, no matter how many times I delete and re-deploy it. This has happened before too and it gets fine after a few hours. I assume it to be a rate-limiting error but the error statement doesn't mention it to be one.
What Happens

I deploy Service A via KServe.
It spins up, but the Knative Route says “certificate provisioning failed.”
I check the corresponding Certificate resource. It exists but is in a Ready: False state. Here are the events:

│ Events:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│   Type    Reason     Age    From                                       Message                                                                                                                                                             │
│   ----    ------     ----   ----                                       -------                                                                                                                                                             │
│   Normal  Issuing    6m48s  cert-manager-certificates-trigger          Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist                                                                                                                        │
│   Normal  Generated  6m48s  cert-manager-certificates-key-manager      Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "route-aa044b4b-xyz-xyz-xyz-xyz-w6h4b"                                                              │
│   Normal  Requested  6m48s  cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "route-xyz-xyz-4119-xyz-xyz-1"                                                                              │

When I describe the CertificateRequest, it says it’s “Waiting on certificate issuance from order.”
Debugging Steps
Following the cert-manager ACME debugging docs, I looked at:

Certificate –> stuck with Ready: False.

CertificateRequest –> “Waiting on certificate issuance from order.”

Order –> it’s in a pending state with “challenges” listed (http-01, dns-01, tls-alpn-01).

Challenge –> Below is what I see post describing the resource:
Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request
"http://my-service-A.default.my-domain.sslip.io/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>":
Get "https://my-service-A.default.my-domain.sslip.io/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>":
read tcp <redacted>:<redacted>-><redacted>:443: read: connection reset by peer
State: pending

Essentially, the ACME server’s HTTP-01 self-check is failing with “connection reset by peer.”


Observations

This only happens with Service A.

I have other Inference Services that, when deployed, immediately get certificates just fine.

I tried switching to the Let’s Encrypt staging environment, but the same error occurs for Service A.

In the cluster, I noticed that autoTLS is enabled in Knative Serving. I disabled it and redeployed the inference service to no positive change.

The failing domain is something like:
my-service-A.default.my-domain.sslip.io

Other services use a similar pattern but don’t have issues.

The Secret for Service A is “Opaque” instead of “kubernetes.io/tls (it is a temporary secret). For the successful services, the Secret is always “kubernetes.io/tls.”



Key Question

Why is this one Inference Service stuck with “connection reset by peer” during HTTP-01 challenge, while other Inference Services are fine? Have I deployed it too many times?


What I’ve Tried

Deleting the old Secret and letting cert-manager re-issue it. It re-creates the Secret with type: Opaque again.
Switching to Let’s Encrypt staging clusterIssuer. Same error.
Verifying no immediate “429 rate-limit” messages.
Comparing the other working Inference Services. They also rely on Knative + cert-manager, but somehow do get a valid certificate.

